# Load segmented views in ViewController but UISegmentControl is in UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created a UIView class (SegmentControl.swift) and added the UISegmentControl using an xib. I have another viewcontroller where I refer this UIView class to add the segment control.

My question here is since I have the UISegmentControl in another UIView class, how will I update the index and load the respective containerViews in the ViewController?

`@IBAction func didChangeIndex(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) { }` will work only if I have Segment control in ViewController.

Please provide your suggestions on how can I load the containerviews when the UIControlSegment is in another class.

This is the code I have:

**SegmentControl.swift**

```
class SegmentControl: UIView {

  @IBOutlet weak var segmentView: UISegmentedControl!
  // Loading nibs are there.. just that I didn't include here

  func create(titles: [String]) {
       items.enumerated().forEach { (index, item) in
           segmentView.setTitle(item, forSegmentAt: index)
       }
   }   
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
func showSegmentControl() {
    let segmentedView = GenericSegmentedView.create(items: ["A", "B"])
    stackView.addArrangedSubView(segmentedView)
}
```

Two container views --> aInfoView and bInfoView are intialised in View Controller.

How will I load them on switching the segments since they are in UIView class. I couldnt find any answers here. Please help!

Thank you!!

Comment: This is a really nice explanation: https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a target to the segmented control even if it's contained within another view.  The segmented control is an accessible property on your `SegmentControl` class.  From the `SegmentControl`'s parent view controller add the target action to the your `SegmentControl`'s child `segmentView`.

```
func showSegmentControl() {
    let segmentedView = GenericSegmentedView.create(items: ["A", "B"])
    stackView.addArrangedSubView(segmentedView)
    segmentedView.segmentView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentControlChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
// Function will be called when value changed on the SegmentControl's segmentView
@objc func segmentControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    print(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

Something as aside, interchanging `segmentControl` and `segmentView` can be confusing to people not familiar with your code.  Maybe a more descriptive name for the `SegmentControl` like `SegmentControlContainer` or something would help make the distinction.